using CCS, Timer.h params are red, do I have a version problem? dependency problem? not sure where to look for solutions
no one has responded to my other question where I tried to implement timer.h but my Timer_Handle and Timer_Params are undefined.
How do I define a timer in code composer studio in gpiointerrupt.c
I looked into the Timer.h import and most of the enums, are also red so I wonder if I have a problem with my file structure or version of ccs maybe? any advice on where I could look or what docs to reference would be appreciated.

I'm writing a state machine to blink LED lights on a ti 3220x Launchxl if that matters
Timer_Handle and Timer_Params are red and undefined if I try to build project
void initTimer(void) {

    Timer_Handle timer0;
    Timer_Params params;
    Timer_init();
    Timer_Params_init(&params);
    params.period = 500000;
    params.periodUnits = Timer_PERIOD_US;
    params.timerMode = Timer_CONTINUOUS_CALLBACK;
    params.timerCallback = timerCallback;

     timer0 = Timer_open(CONFIG_TIMER_0, &params);

     if (timer0 == NULL) {
         /* Failed to initialized timer */
         while (1) {}
     }

     if (Timer_start(timer0) == Timer_STATUS_ERROR) {
         /* Failed to start timer */
         while (1) {}
     }
}


I think your question is about Code Composer Studio's building code mechanism. If it is, SO is not for this. Highly recommend to read article-guidelines

@Brian Fulton – What's that Timer_PeriodUnits?
